# External Javascript File: Correct way to pass configuration parameters

Tags: javascript

I have an external javascript file called `test.js` as seen below. This file needs user configuration parameters passed to it, in this case `user` and `show` values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
  user = '123';
  show = 'appts';
//-->
</script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/widgets/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Above is currently how I tell 3rd parties to add the script to their own site. However, I cannot help to feel this is a bad way to pass these values i.e. clashes.

Is the way I have done it acceptable? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer would be to append something to your variable names, such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
  widget_test_12331_user = '123';
  widget_test_12331_show = 'appts';
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Um... I'm totally claiming that as an April Fools joke. Yes, that's what happened. Ahem.

Answer (score 2):

You can stick to namespace convention "reverted domain":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
if (!org) var org = {};
if (!org.mylibrary_domain) org.mylibrary_domain = {};
if (!org.mylibrary_domain.settings) org.mylibrary_domain.settings = {};
org.mylibrary_domain.settings.user = '123';
org.mylibrary_domain.settings.show = 'appts';
//-->
</script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/widgets/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the concept of javascript namespace ([How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)).

so you can add another js file named testConfig.js, which include :

```
var yourAppNamespaceTestConfig = {
    user: function(){ return '123' ;} ,
    show: function(){ return 'appts';}
};
```

then inside test.js, you can read the config by:

```
var user = yourAppNamespaceTestConfig.user();
var show = yourAppNamespaceTestConfig.show();
```

And if you're more about OO, try Coffeescript (http://coffeescript.org/). They introduce OO to your javascript.

Comment: But why do you need functions for retrieving `user` and `show` value?